# What is the Laplace form of the pendulum equation derived from the equation of motion of a pendulum?

Tags: trigonometry, laplace-transform, harmonic-functions

Simple question really.

$L (d^2/dt^2) \theta = - g \cdot \theta $

Or

$ I \theta \ddot (t) + m \cdot g \cdot l \cdot sin ( \theta \cdot t ) $

Assuming $ sin \theta = \theta $ for angles less than about 15 degrees.

Is it

$ L(s) \cdot s^2 = - g \cdot s $

Or

$ M(s) \cdot g \cdot l \cdot (s/(s^2 + \theta)) $

Or something else?!

I think I know what the Laplace transforms of trig functions are, and of normal time-based variables, but how do you deal with m*g*l?

I guess you can make theta become s if your variables are of the form $u(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

The Laplace transform is from $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ so as we consider $t \ge 0$ we can proceed obtaining

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\theta(t)\right) = \Theta(s) = \frac{I(s\theta_0+\theta'_0)}{I s^2+m g l}
$$

and after anti transformation

$$
\theta(t) = \left(\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac {m g l}{I}}t\right)\theta_0 + \sqrt{\frac{I}{m g l}}\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac {m g l}{I}}t\right)\theta'_0\right)u(t)
$$

with $u(t)$ the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Thank you. I also found a fantastic worked example here too: 
 http://www2.ensc.sfu.ca/people/faculty/saif/ctm/examples/pend/invpen.html